# How do I round down with parseFloat when the decimal is truncated due to precision?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
parseFloat(2099985998.998995491692253777)
// Actual -> 2099985998.9989955
// Desired -> 2099985998.9989954
```

I only want to truncate the decimals instead of rounding.

Comment: That doesn't actually have anything to do with `parseFloat`.

Comment: `2099985998.998995491692253777` has too much precision and can't fit inside a numeric type at all without truncation.  This has nothing to do with `parseFloat`

Comment: @pilchard No that does not answer my question because i don't know how many decimals of precision there will be - i want the max. But that depends on the size of the integer before the decimal.

Comment: It *is* giving you the max amount of precision.  It's truncating the number to fit inside a numeric type.  It only truncates as much as it needs to fit.  It isn't doing a rounding operation.

Comment: @Amy I see. I just tested it in the console again. how can i get javascript to truncate instead of rounding when the precision is too large? If you put 2099985998.998995491692253777 into the console it rounds it up to 2099985998.9989955. If it truncated then it would be 2099985998.9989954

Comment: @DylanKerler It is truncating.  You can confirm this to yourself by converting your number to binary by hand, then doing the truncation, then converting back to decimal.  The reason it appears to round the last digit is because the truncation occurs in binary, not decimal.  If you want to avoid that effect entirely, you'd have to start with a string representation of the number, and do some string operations to truncate it yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks, it looks like i should probably take a different approach to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're parsing a string value, what about just truncating the sourcestring first?

```
const quantityDecimals = 7
source = source.substr(0,source.indexOf('.') + quantityDecimals)
parseFloat(source)
```